# Gensim - AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FixedCorpusWeight'

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I've just installed Gensim and have run a test. 484 tests run successfully however I hit an error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: testAddMorphemesToEmbeddings (gensim.test.test_varembed_wrapper.TestVarembed)
Test add morphemes to Embeddings
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/franciskim/Downloads/gensim-2.0.0/gensim/test/test_varembed_wrapper.py", line 56, in testAddMorphemesToEmbeddings
    vectors=varembed_model_vector_file, morfessor_model=varembed_model_morfessor_file)
  File "/Users/franciskim/Downloads/gensim-2.0.0/gensim/models/wrappers/varembed.py", line 69, in load_varembed_format
    morfessor_model = morfessor.MorfessorIO().read_binary_model_file(morfessor_model)
  File "/Users/franciskim/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/morfessor/io.py", line 179, in read_binary_model_file
    model = pickle.load(fobj)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FixedCorpusWeight' on <module 'morfessor.baseline' from '/Users/franciskim/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/morfessor/baseline.py'>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can only find 1 other instance of this happening on the internet, but there are no answers to this yet.